# Plone Archetypes redirection after creation

Tags: python, redirect, plone, archetypes

I've searched in Internet for a while, but I haven't found out anything useful...

I want to do something as simple as redirect the page to the listing page (folder) after save/create an AT content type.

I already know I have to use validate_integrity.cpy and write my redirect's logic there, but the file isn't run...

So far this is an example of my validate_integrity.cpy:

```
## Script (Python) "validate_integrity"
##title=Validate Integrity
##bind container=container
##bind context=context
##bind namespace=
##bind script=script
##bind state=state
##bind subpath=traverse_subpath
##parameters=
##

from Products.Archetypes import PloneMessageFactory as _
from Products.Archetypes.utils import addStatusMessage

request = context.REQUEST
errors = {}
errors = context.validate(REQUEST=request, errors=errors, data=1, metadata=0)
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
if errors:
    message = _(u'Please correct the indicated errors.')
    addStatusMessage(request, message, type='error')
    return state.set(status='failure', errors=errors)
else:
    message = _(u'Changes saved.')
    stat = 'created'

    # Redirection after saving edition forms
    redirects = {'Multifile': context.aq_parent.absolute_url_path() + '/multifile'}
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    if context.portal_type in redirects:
        redirect = 'redirect_to:string:${portal_url}' + redirects[context.portal_type]
        state.setNextAction(redirect)
    else:
        stat = 'success'

    addStatusMessage(request, message)
    return state.set(status=stat)
```

**RESOLUTION**

I just needed to write the following upgrade step:

```
from Acquisition import aq_inner, aq_parent
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName

def upgrade(tool):
    portal = aq_parent(aq_inner(tool))
    setup = portal.portal_setup
    setup.runImportStepFromProfile('profile-my.addon:default', 'skins')
```

[Useful info about upgrade steps here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821498/is-there-a-good-reference-list-for-the-names-of-the-genericsetup-import-steps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *.metadata file might be missing or have an action that routes to a different location than you expect: http://docs.plone.org/old-reference-manuals/forms/using_cmfformcontroller.html

The default metadata for content_edit lives in Products/Archetypes/skins/archetypes/content_edit.cpy.metadata:

```
...
[actions]
action.success = traverse_to:string:validate_integrity
action.success_add_reference = redirect_to:python:object.REQUEST['last_referer']
action.failure = traverse_to_action:string:edit
action.next_schemata = traverse_to_action:string:edit
```

Is your action button value "success"?

Comment: This documentationwas very useful, but I just needed an upgrade step, thanks!